# Actionscript 3 - Making one MovieClip the hitArea of another

Tags: actionscript-3, addeventlistener, event-listener

Suppose I have a rectangle whose instance name is

```
rectangle
```

and suppose I have a square right beside the rectangle and the squares instance name is

```
square
```

. Now, I want the rectangle to hitArea to be it's own area as well as the square's area. So, if I have these three event listeners:

```
rectangle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rectangleClick);   
rectangle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, rectangleHover);  
rectangle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, rectangleOut);
```

How do I make it so that when I hover over, hover out of and click the rectangle OR square, the rectangle event listeners get called?

Note: the event listeners have

```
event.target
```

and

```
event.currentTarget
```

so I cannot do a simple

```
square.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rectangleClick);
```

since I need the rectangle to be the

```
event.target
```

.

Comment: What is `rectangle`? If it's `MovieClip`, then is it ok to add square to rectangle using `addChild`?

Comment: @RajneeshGaikwad rectangle is a MovieClip yes but I do not want to add square to rectangle. Basically, I have a rectangle with a shadow filter (the shadow outlines the rectangle) and I don't want the shadow to be visible on the right side of rectangle so I decided to place square on top of the right side of the rectangle (square is the same color as rectangle) and that way, square will cover the shadow on the right side of rectangle. If I added square to rectangle, then the whole MC will have a shadow again which I don't want. Long story short, I can't add the square to the rectangle :)

Comment: Then, why don't you add shadow to separate `MovieClip` e.g. `rectangleShadow` add place it beneath `rectangle`? Keep only three sides (3 outlines with no fill and no outline where you do not want shadow) in this `rectangleShadow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your listeners are referencing the Rectangle only, just identify it by its instance name and NOT **event.target**. Now you can apply the same addEventListner() method to the Square, and the Rectangle will be acted upon, in either case, by the listener function.